# How to display parsed data in a ListView in another Activity?

Tags: android

I am able to display the names and position in a `ListView` in the same activity through ksoap2 but I want to display the names and position in another activity in a `ListView`.

I don't know how to do that. Can some one guide me on this?

This is my code:

```
package com.example.rotaryclubnew;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;



import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Searchcontactswithposition extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


    EditText name1,pos;
    Button searching;


    public static String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://tempuri.org/Search";

   public static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

    public static String METHOD_NAME2 = "Search";

    private static String URL = "http://115.119.182.114/Rotaryclub/RotaryService.asmx"; 

    TextView txtdata;
    ListView lv;
     List<String> contactRecords = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.searchcontactswithposition);
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        name1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1withname);
        pos=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1withposition);

        searching=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2search);
        searching.setOnClickListener(this);

        //txtdata=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewtodisplayname);

        //abs();
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    /*  Intent i = new Intent(Searchcontactswithposition.this,Displaydetails.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("Nameofperson", name1.getText().toString());
        extras.putString("Positionofcontacts", pos.getText().toString());
        i.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(i);*/




             Thread networkThread = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      try {
                         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME2);     

                         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                         envelope.dotNet=true;
                         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


                         HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                        // ht.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);
                         if( name1.getText().toString().equals("")&&pos.getText().toString().equals("")){

                            Toast.makeText(Searchcontactswithposition.this, "please enter details", 3000).show();
                                /*Intent i=new Intent(Searchcontactswithposition.this, Rotary_main.class);
                                startActivity(i);*/
                         }
                         request.addProperty("Name",name1.getText().toString());//pass the parameters
                         request.addProperty("Position",pos.getText().toString());

                         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                         ht.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);


                      final SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

        runOnUiThread (new Runnable()
                   { 
                     public void run() 
                     {


                         int count=result.getPropertyCount();
                         System.out.println("in main count "+count);
                         for (int i = 0; i <count; i++) 
                          {
                              SoapObject result1=(SoapObject) result.getProperty(i);//get the result 
                              if(result!=null)
                              {
                              contactRecords.add("Name "+result1.getProperty(2).toString()+"\n"+"Position "+result1.getProperty(1).toString());
                              name1.setText("");
                              pos.setText("");

                             System.out.println("in for loop "+"Name "+result1.getProperty(2).toString()+"\n"+"Position "+result1.getProperty(1).toString());
                          }

                          }
                      }
                   });
                   }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                     handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);//call the handle to display the data in a listview

                    }
                  };
                            /*lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                              @Override
                              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

                                // you can do ur work according to selected string or index here... 
                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),lv.getAdapter().getItem(position)+" is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                             }

                            });*/

                  networkThread.start();//start the network thred




    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler()
        {
            @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg)
            {

                ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
            aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Searchcontactswithposition.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contactRecords);
            lv.setAdapter(aa);
           // aa.clear();

            }
        };

    /*public void abs()
    {

        if( name1.getText().toString().equals("")||pos.getText().toString().equals("")){

                Intent i=new Intent(Searchcontactswithposition.this, Rotary_main.class);
                startActivity(i);

            Toast.makeText(this, "please enter details",4000).show();   
            }*/



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass contactRecords ArrayList to Another Activity using Intent as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Searchcontactswithposition.this, Other_Activity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("contactRecords_list", contactRecords);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in Other_Activity get contactRecords as in onCreate method of Activity as:

```
contactRecords = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("contactRecords_list");
```

Now, you are able to use contactRecords  ArrayList for ListView Adapter as data source on your other activity

Comment: i am getting an error ,if i am using putStringArrayListExtra in my first activity.compiler is suggesting me to put parceableArraylist

Comment: no this is not possible becuase String type ArrayList is by default parceable so you just need to use putStringArrayListExtra for passing ArrayList of type String and if you have ArrayList of custom objects of a class which implemets parceable interface then you will need to use parceableArraylist for passing ArrayList to another class